# How to update DIV content in Firefox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have this code in javascript to show time in div and update it:

```
  if (!document.all)
    return

  var Digital=new Date()
  var hours=Digital.getHours()
  var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
  var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
  var dn="AM" 

  if (hours>12){
   dn="PM"
   hours=hours-12
  }

  if (hours==0)
   hours=12

  if (minutes<=9)
   minutes="0"+minutes

  if (seconds<=9)
   seconds="0"+seconds
   var ctime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds
   $("#c").text(ctime);

   setTimeout("show2()",1000)
}

window.onload=show2
```

and I have this div :

```
<div id=""c></div>
```

in IE every thing is ok but when I try it in Firefox, it's not working.

I also tried to use

```
c.innerHTML=ctime
```

and it's not working.

What is the right way to do it on both IE and Firefox?

Thanks

Comment: Obvious question but you do have JS enabled right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's the first line

```
if (!document.all)
    return
```

since .all property exists on Explorer and Opera only.

You are preventing other browser to continue code execution

Answer (score 2):

Try `<div id="c"></div>` and `document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = ctime;`

and get rid of `if (!document.all) return`

Comment: If that $("#c") is JQuery, I think. And it resolves to document.getElementById('c').

Comment: It's tagged jQuery so that should be jQuery :)

Comment: Btw, innerHTML is more dangerous than setting the text since innerHTML doesn't escape anything

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
  if (!document.all)
    return
```

since document.all is an IE only extension, and FireFox doesn't support it